# Textfield data hide when scroll tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I am developing IOS App. Multiple textfield add on tableviewcell.when enter data on texfield than scroll tableview textfield data hide. How to manage textfield on tableview.Please Help me and thanks in advance[image]

code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableViews{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 100;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    }
    UITextField *textFieldName = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0f, 3.0f, 80.0f, 36.0f)];
    [cell addSubview:textFieldName];
    [textFieldName setDelegate:self];
    textFieldName.tag = indexPath.row+1;

    UILabel *line = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(96.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 50.0f)];
    line.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:214.0/255.0 green:214.0/255.0 blue:214.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [cell addSubview:line];

    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    tableView.allowsSelection=NO;
    return cell;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([textField tag]-1) inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *Cell = [_dairyTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Comment: once you scroll ,cell reuse again.so text field cannot show previous data.You need to store text field  text on character  should range delegate method and store it into an array so you need to get data once you scroll and assign it to text field again.

Comment: keep your entered textfield in temporary dictionary with key indexPath row, Set it to textfield ion reload

Comment: You draw nice UI design.. I liked it. (y)

Answer (score 0):

### **How to deal with `UITextField` Value in `UITableView` :**

1. First of all you have to create mutable Array with count equal to the number of `UITextField`.
2. In `cellForRow` do `cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row`sothat you can identify each `UItextField`.
3. Save every `UITextField`value in the array in the same sequence with each character change. So, do code in `textdidChange` delegate method of `UITextField` by identifing the `UITextfield` by its tag as `textfield.tag`.
4. Whenever user enters or edit the text, you get that text in array.
5. Now in `cellForRow` add below line:

`cell.textfiled.text = arrDataText[index.row]`